# Method from subclass is called instead of local method

Tags: java, android

I have the next two classes (Fragments):

```
public class FAboutUs extends FDetails {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        System.out.println("BUBUBU :: AboutUs - onCreate");
        View view = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        this.init(view, savedInstanceState);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    protected void init(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        System.out.println("BUBUBU :: AboutUs - init");
        //        super.init(view, savedInstanceState);
    }
}


public class FDetails extends FGlobalBase {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        System.out.println("BUBUBU :: Details - onCreate");
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.f_details, null);
        FDetails.this.init(view, savedInstanceState);
        return view;
    }


    @Override
    protected void init(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        System.out.println("BUBUBU :: Details - init");
        super.init(view, savedInstanceState);

    }
```

}

I have this printed in my logs:

```
BUBUBU :: AboutUs - onCreate
BUBUBU :: Details - onCreate
BUBUBU :: AboutUs - init
BUBUBU :: AboutUs - init
```

I instantiate `FAboutUs` and it starts from `onCreateView` inside `FAboutUs`. 
Why does `FDetails` call the `init` method inside `AboutUs` instead of its own method? Am I missing some sort of object oriented programming thing pertaining to `protected` methods or .... what is going on ?!?!

**EDIT**
It seems `FDetails.this.init(view, savedInstanceState);` is calling the `init` method from `FAboutUs` instead of its own `init` method. Why ?!

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "local method". C♯ and Scala both have local functions/methods, but Java doesn't.

Comment: Can you add the instantiation code? And then method execution?

Comment: That's how inheritance and virtual method dispatch works. It will call the most specific method. Since you have an instance of `FAboutUs`, the `init` method in `FAboutUs` is more specific than the `init` method in `FDetails`.

Comment: @JornVernee I always though that worked for `abstract` methods and classes only!

Comment: `abstract` makes an extending class to require implementing such a thing. It works without `abstract` though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following code:

```
FAboutUs aboutUs = new FAboutUs();
FDetails details = aboutUs;

aboutUs.init();
details.init();
```

Two last calls call the same method, that is, `FAboutUs#init()` method.

This is because `init()` method is overriden in `FAboutUs` from `FDetails`, and the object referenced by both references actually has `FAboutUs` class. In terms of C++ it would be called virtual.

When a call to such a method occurs, Java Virtual Machine looks for the most specific method (that is, a method defined on the level of inheritance closest to the actual object class) with the same signature.

Only non-private methods may be overriden.

More info: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html

Comment: Yeah, but it still doesn't make any sense to me why `FDetails.this.init()` won't call the method in `FDetails`. I tell it specifically to call that method ... I'm very confused.

Comment: Here, only the actual class of the object is important. It's `FAboutUs`, so it's version of `init()` method is called. The syntax you use is just for qualifying `this` reference (as with embedded classes there may be several different `this` references in scope) and not for changing how method dispatch works.

Comment: @RomanPuchkovskiy The fact that the `init()` method is overridden by the subclass is not enough. The reason the for that is the instantiation - `= new FAboutUs()` - **this** causes on runtime to run the subclass `init()` method. If it was instantiated with the `= new FDetails()` it wouldn't have happened.

Comment: oh...my...god. I do realize now what you're saying, and I completely knew these things ... but for my entire programming career apparently I've forgotten about this in the past 2 years